# How do I capture inside non-capture with * quantifier?

Tags: regex

I have a pattern:

```
abc77cat77dot77bingo77secretff
```

And want to capture cat, dot, bingo, and secret.

This is what I have:

```
(?:77(.+?))*ff
```

And it only captures secret.  How can I capture all the words above?  I'm attempting this on https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: move it out from non-capture....

Comment: which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lookaronds you can use this regex:

```
(?<=77|ff)(\w+?)(?=77|ff)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vM8nI8/1)

This will match 1 or more word chars the either preceded by `77` or `ff` or followed by `77` or `ff`.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of using lookarounds.  This solution is the most straightforward.

Comment: My answer does not take into account that *abc* should not be a match. Your's does! +1

Answer (score 1):

You might use this:

```
(.*?)(77|ff)
```

I'm simply using two capturing groups: One for the words and one for the delimiters. Note the `?` after `.*`. It means *ungreedy* or *lazy* match. Also don't miss to pass the `g` option (stands for *global*).

https://regex101.com/r/wF3nD3/1

Comment: If I go to regex101.com and click PY it doesn't work, yet your link does.  What gives?

Comment: Have you specified the `g` option?

Comment: The g helps, but I don't want two capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the regex expression your looking for would be

```
(?:77([a-z]+)*)
```

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html
[image]